# How to train ResNet101 model from scratch in Caffe?

Tags: caffe

I'm using the [DeepLab_v2](https://bitbucket.org/aquariusjay/deeplab-public-ver2) version of Caffe in order to do semantic segmentation. I can finetune the ResNet101 using imagenet model,  but I cannot train the model from scratch using custom data. Did anyone have similar experience and managed to solve this issue?

This is how a functional block of the ResNet looks like, that I'm currently using for training:

```
layer {
    bottom: "data"
    top: "conv1"
    name: "conv1"
    type: "Convolution"
    param {
           name: "conv1_0"
               lr_mult: 1
               decay_mult: 1
        }
        convolution_param {
        num_output: 64
        kernel_size: 3
        pad: 1
        stride: 2
        bias_term: false
        weight_filler {
          type: "msra"

        }
    }
}

layer {
    bottom: "conv1"
    top: "conv1"
    name: "bn_conv1"
    type: "BatchNorm"
    batch_norm_param {
        use_global_stats: true
    }
    param {
        name: "bn_conv1_0"
          lr_mult: 0
    }
    param {
        name: "bn_conv1_1"
          lr_mult: 0
        }
    param {
        name: "bn_conv1_2"
          lr_mult: 0
        }
}

layer {
    bottom: "conv1"
    top: "conv1"
    name: "scale_conv1"
    type: "Scale"
    scale_param {
        bias_term: true
        filler {
          value: 0.5    
        }
        bias_filler {
          value: -2
        }
    }
    param {
        name: "scale_conv1_0"
          lr_mult: 0
    }
    param {
        name: "scale_conv1_1"
          lr_mult: 0
    }
}

layer {
    top: "conv1"
    bottom: "conv1"
    name: "conv1_relu"
    type: "ReLU"
}
```

I tried all kinds of variations including `use_global_stats: false`. I am able to train one single block of the type above, but when I try to use all 101 layers, the model does not converge anymore.
Any ideas?

Comment: Do you actually succeeding in sharing the parameters of `"BatchNorm"` layer with the `"Scale"` layer following it? I am having trouble making caffe do so... See [this git issue](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/5171). Do you happen to have the same issue as well? Do you see `Sharing parameter 'bn_conv1_0'  owned by layer 'bn_conv1' , param index 0` in the log?

Comment: Hmm I'm not getting that error. Besides I'm not trying to share parameters among the different BatchNorm layers. In the ResNet model every BatchNorm layer has his own name (and hence I assume his own parameters). Besides do you know what the 3 `param` s  in the BatchNorm layer are for? (mean,variance,moving-average?)

Comment: (1) the line `Sharing parameter 'bn_conv1_0' owned by layer 'bn_conv1' , param index 0` is **not** an error message, it is actually telling you caffe did what you asked from it. If you don't see this line then something is **not** carried out as you requested. (2) You are not sharing parameters between `"BatchNorm"` layers, but between `"BatchNorm"` and the `"Scale"` layer after it. (3) The three internal parameters are mean, variance, and the bias correction.